Why Does LightRAG with Local LLM (Gemma2:2B via Ollama) Fail After Server Restart?
I am using LightRAG with a local LLM (gemma2:2B) through Ollama. I am encountering a strange issue.
Initially, I passed a section of data to LightRAG and tested it with a query to verify if it returns the correct response. The response was accurate, indicating that the LLM processed the data correctly. However, after stopping the Ollama server for any reason and restarting it, I tried performing the exact same operation (with the same data, query, model, and resources). This time, the LLM failed to process the data and returned an error. This behavior continues for other models as well.
What could be causing this issue, and how can I resolve it?
